# How do I get Javascript and PHP to order a JSON response the same way?

Tags: php, javascript

I have this Javascript which receives a JSON from the Google API server, and then outputs the content (note my code has been simplified for clarity):

```
function init() {
  gapi.client.setApiKey('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
  gapi.client.load('blogger', 'v2', function() {
    var request = gapi.client.blogger.posts.list({
      'blogId': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      'fields': 'items(content,title)'
    });
    request.execute(function(response) {
      for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++)
      {
        $(aDiv).append(response.items[i].title);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

And I have this PHP code which does essentially the same thing:

```
$recentBlog = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/posts?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"), true);
foreach ($recentBlog['items'] as $item)
{
    echo $item[`title`];
}
```

The problem is that the output from each code is in a different order. The Javascript outputs to the page in the order, from top to bottom, `2, 1, 0`. The PHP goes, from top to bottom, `0, 1, 2`. What I need is for the "latest" item to be at the top, so I need both to be, in order of top to bottom, `2, 1, 0`.

Other than the different methods of calling for the JSON data, which I assume brings back the exact same response, it seems that the only real difference is that one is a `for()` loop, and the other is a `foreach()` loop. I can't see how that would make a difference, so there must be something else I'm missing.

Whatever the cause, in my current situation, I need the PHP to conform to the Javascript's ordering, so that most recent is at the top of the page. Or, in other words, going from top to bottom, `2, 1, 0`. How do I get that to happen?

Comment: *"Other than the different methods of calling for the JSON data, which I assume brings back the exact same response..."* Why would you assume that? If you bothered to check, you probably wouldn't have had to ask this question

Comment: @Phil: Actually, I can check, and the data is ordered the same. So your impolite comment is incorrect.

Comment: Never read the comments.

Comment: I'm having trouble believing this. A JSON array has guaranteed order and PHP won't change that around via `json_decode`. Got any examples? A `console.log(response)` from your JS and a `print_r($recentBlog)` from PHP aught to provide a decent comparison

Comment: @Phil, I'm not asserting that `json_decode` is changing it. What I am saying is that if I dump the raw JSON data either from PHP or JSON before any processing, it looks exactly the same, so I thought both PHP and Javascript would step through the keys in the same order. However, after I process it with my code and then output to a browser, the order of items is different. I don't know why or where in my code the change happens, which is why I came here with my question.

Comment: I'm asserting that your code is not changing anything. The response from the JS API must order the items differently than the response from the REST API. I will believe this until proven otherwise.

Comment: @Phil. Okay. Believe as you will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) function.

```
$recentBlog = json_decode(...);
$recentBlogReversed = array_reverse($recentBlog['items']);
```

Comment: I'd say the array to be reversed would be `$recentBlog['items']`

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. It's an array of objects. For some reason I wasn't registering that.